# How to import and read a large data set, with respect to time?

Tags: matlab, struct, dataset, simulink, mat

Diving straight to the question:

Values.mat when loaded into matlab reveals a 1x1 struct. Within which there are following:

Info {1x1 Struct}

X {1x1 Struct}

Y {1x31 Struct}

Description {1x1 Struct}

My data resides in the Y. When i open each struct, there is more data. Although, data of interest is only one of the data set, lets call it DATA.

DATA 1x27048

I know the total simulation time to generate DATA is 27 secs @ 0.001; i.e. each value is generated after 0.001 sec.

I have already seperated the required data from Values.mat into a seperate values_sep.mat.

```
values_sep.mat {27048x2} : 27048x1 = original data;27048x2 = TIME(0,0.001,0.002...27);
```

My intention is to read this data set as per defined time is

TIME----Data

0.001 - value_1

0.002 - value_2 ... 0.00N - value_N.

Whenever I try to read this data in SIMULINK all get is colored lines on the scope. All other methods have also been useless(from workspace, as a 27048x2 (with time)).

Please guide me how to read this data set as per time.

*REPLY TO THE 1st Comment **@am304***

[image: ERROR SCREEN SHOT]

> Please check the added image:
>
> A - I defined the data as struct.
>
> B - When I try to add the name of the created MAT file (KLPD.mat), I
>   get this error.
>
> C & D - explanation of the data I create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block, but make sure to arrange your data so that the first column is the time data points and the second column the actual data.

If you tick "Interpolate data", Simulink will interpolate your data for the time steps that are not in your original data.

If you use a variable-step solver, set the maximum step size to 0.001, or use a fixed-step solver with a 0.001s time step. Set you simulation stop time to 27s.

Comment: Your signal is of dimension 1 (you only have one signal) so you need to define `KPLD.signals.dimensions = 1`. You misunderstood what the dimension of a signal is. Read the documentation for more info.